# Idempotent endomorphism on finite monogenic monoid onto its subgroup

Tags: group-theory, semigroups, monoid, finite-semigroups, semigroup-homomorphism

Let $S = \langle x ;x^m = x^{m+n} \rangle $ be a monogenic monoid, where $m,n\in\mathbb N$ are least such that $a^m = a^{m+n}$. Then $S$ contains its maximal subgroup $G\cong \mathbb Z_n$.

> Define a homomorhpism $\varphi : S\to S$ such that $\varphi (S) = G$ and $\varphi^2 =\varphi$

We need to map everything onto $G = \{a^m, a^{m+1},\ldots, a^{m+n-1}\}$.
Does anyone have any ideas/clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. Let $e$ be the idempotent of $G$. Then define $\varphi$ by setting $\varphi(s) = se$.

Comment: $$\varphi (st) = (st)e \overset{?} = (se)(te) = \varphi(s)\varphi (t)$$
The idempotent clearly commutes with elements of $G$ (it's the identity). Am I allowed to say $$\varphi (st) = s(te) = s\varphi (t) = s(e\varphi (t)) = \varphi (s)\varphi (t) $$

Comment: it's also clear $\varphi$ maps onto $G$

Comment: Since $G$ is a group, $se = s = es$ for all $s \in G$. So yes, your argument is correct.